# await to set of operations to be executed without promises

Tags: javascript

I try to figure out a way to use `await` with the following:
I loop through an array. Then I check some condition on each item. If the condition applies, then I execute an async operation. This is how it would look:

```
for(exampleItem in exampleArray) {
    const condition = SOME_SERVER_OPERATIONS_TO_CHECK;
    if(condition) {
        await AN_ASYNC_OPERATION
    }
}
 
// More code to execute
```

However, these operations executions are independent.
BUT- I don't want to execute `// More code to execute` untill all the executions complete.

I wish to do something like this:

```
await for(exampleItem in exampleArray) {
    const condition = SOME_SERVER_OPERATIONS_TO_CHECK;
    if(condition) {
        AN_ASYNC_OPERATION
    }
}

// More code to execue
```

Meaning, I wan't to execute the `// More code the execute` only after all the `AN_ASYNC_OPERATION` have been completed. This is like `Promise.all`. Is there a way to do it only with `await?`

Comment: Do you want to run the async operation sequentially or in parallel?

Comment: @VLAZ Parallel.

Comment: OK, in that case why avoid `Promise.all`?

Comment: SOME_SERVER_OPERATIONS_TO_CHECK sounds like it's async, too.  Is it?

Comment: Also the premise of the question is mistaken... async / await doesn't avoid promises.  It conceals them in prettier syntax.  Promises == good and  Promise.all() == all good.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
const operations = [];
for(exampleItem in exampleArray) {
   const condition = SOME_SERVER_OPERATIONS_TO_CHECK;
   if(condition) {
        operations.push(AN_ASYNC_OPERATION);
   }
}
await Promise.all(operations);

// more code to execute
```

Comment: and ofc looping is easier with `.map` in case you use ES6

Answer (score 0):

You could build up an array of promises:

```
 await Promise.all(
    array
    .filter(someServerOperation)
    .map(someAsyncOperation)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple answers for the problem statement. Also, check out for..of loop using async and await.

```
// Series loop
async (tasks) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    
    // for loop will wait for promise to resolve
    const result = await db.get(tasks[i]);
    console.log(result);
  }
}

// Parallel loop
async (tasks) => {
  let promises = [];
  
  // all promises will be added to array in order
  for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    promises.push(db.get(tasks[i]));
  }
  
  // Promise.all will await all promises in the array to resolve
  // then it will itself resolve to an array of the results. 
  // results will be in order of the Promises passed, 
  // regardless of completion order
  
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(results);
}
```